# creating table from import from two files

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I just started using Wolfram *Mathematica*.
I have two files  with numbers:

```
x=Import["c"\.path here..\x.txt","Table"];
y=Import["c"\.path here..\y.txt","Table"];
```

now I have two tables x and y. I want to combine then to have a one table

> `{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}}`

That I can use to build a graphic using `ListPlot`.
I tried using something like that

```
num={};


l1=length[x]; l2=length[y]; 
Do[num=Append[num,Partition[x[[i]],1]],Append[num,Partition[y[[i]],1]],{i,l1}]
```

so how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shorter and on my machine approx. 2 times faster than [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37215698/6236632):

```
t = Thread[{x, y}]
```

There is no speed difference to the answer given in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215341/creating-table-from-import-from-two-files#comment61966482_37215698) by [agentp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004168/agentp).

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer

```
t=MapThread[List,{x,y}]
```

that it, simple and short

Comment: even shorter `Transpose[{x,y}]`